# ¿Cómo mostrar los detalles de una tabla relacionada en Django REST framework?

Tags: django, django-models, djangorestframework

Quisiera saber como hacer para mostrar los detalles de una tabla relacionada.
por ejemplo:

```py
    class Cajas(models.Model):
        Id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
        Nro_Caja = models.IntegerField()
        Descripcion = models.CharField(max_length=60)
        EmpACargo = models.ForeignKey(Empleados, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

        class Meta:
            ordering = ('Nro_Caja',)

    class Empleados(models.Model):
        Id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
        Usuario = models.CharField(max_length=60)
        Contrasenia = models.CharField(max_length=60)
        Apellido = models.CharField(max_length=60)
        Nombre = models.CharField(max_length=60)
        Dni = models.CharField(max_length=60)
        Telefono = models.CharField(max_length=60)
        Domicilio = models.CharField(max_length=60)
        Puesto = models.CharField(max_length=60)
        Nivel_Acceso = models.IntegerField()
        Rol = models.ForeignKey(Roles, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Quisiera saber como puedo mostrar los detalles del empleado cuando obtengo la caja ya que uso django como api rest, que no solamente me traiga el id del empleado sino que tambien me obtenga todos los campos de los empleados.

Comment: Quieres listar todas las cajas, cada uno con su detalle del empleado?

Comment: Muestrame como tienes tu api, tu serializer y te ayudo :D!

Answer (score 1):

Es cuestión de leer [la documentación](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#nested-relationships), pero primero te dejo un par de recomendaciones de código.

### Recomendaciones

- Primero, sería bueno que leas sobre [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), que es el estándar de código para Python. En particular, tus variables deben estar en *snake case*. Cuando empiezas con mayúsculas parece que fueran clases. Si quieres manter el nombre en la base de datos, puedes [usar el argumento `db_column`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#db-column):

```py
  nro_caja = models.IntegerField(db_column='NroCaja')
```

- Otro tema es que el nombre de la clase del modelo debe ser singular, no plural. Osea, `Empleados` debería ser `Empleado`.

### Nested serializers

Puedes hacer tus serializadores así, haciendo un *override* del serializador por defecto para un `ForeignKey`, que sólo muestra el `id`, por uno que sí muestre un diccionario con datos. Esto es llamado un **serializador anidado**.

```py
from rest_framework import serializers

from .models import Caja, Empleado


class EmpleadoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

  class Meta:
    model = Empleado
    fields = (
      'id',
      'usuario',
      'contrasenia',
      'apellido',
      'nombre',
      'dni',
      'telefono',
      'domicilio',
      'puesto',
      'nivel_acceso',
      'rol',
    )

class CajaSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  emp_a_cargo = EmpleadoSerializer()  # Nested serializer

  class Meta:
    model = Caja
    fields = (
      'id',
      'nro_caja',
      'descripcion',
      'emp_a_cargo',
    )
```

En ambos casos también puedes hacer

```py
  fields = '__all__'
```

Pero es preferible ser explícito en la definición.

Si tienes problemas con la escritura, puedes leer [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60880463/django-rest-framework-nested-serializer-create-method/60881259#60881259) que dejé en otra pregunta (en inglés).